# Is it good idea to implement USB communication in Java using JNI interface where native language is C or C++?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

I have requirement of implementing USB communication in Android phone. I have searched and I come to know that it is difficult to implement in Java. so what I have thought of using JNI interface and implementing code in C or C++ and linking that in Java. hey I am new to JNI so if I missed any terms or did mistake excuse me. but anybody can suggest on that or can give me the alternate solution to implement this.

Comment: This is very vague. Could you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish? In the world of the smartphone, "USB communication" is an extremely broad topic.

Comment: I want to implement file transfer via USB from android phone to PC and PC to android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb - don't use the JNI unless you have to. The JNI is great for number-crunching and heavy lifting, like algorithms. Unless your USB communication involves encryption and other fancy things, I'd strongly advise against it.

First of all, using API calls is a lot more cumbersome using JNI. Furthermore, it'll be a lot harder to debug, you have fewer tools at your disposal to debug the code, and you're more likely to introduce bugs.

Answer (score 2):

When you plug an Android phone into a computer using a USB cable, it will appear as a standard removable mass storage device. From the PC end, file copying is as trivial as it gets. From the Android end, you can't do anything - it would be a massive security flaw if the device could arbitrarily write files to your computer. I would suggest reversing your design pattern, and have the file copy operation done by software on the PC.

If you're trying to implement some sort of data-passing between the phone and PC based on files, I would suggest switching to a more suitable model, e.g. TCP sockets.

Both the file and socket models should be relatively trivial to implement in Java on a PC.

Comment: yes polynomial i was also confused on the direction of communication. so now i will think of communication PC to android phone and will look for TCP spcket. i am still new to this, so if you can give me some hint for how to implement file transfer through TCP socket?

Comment: Such an explanation is beyond the scope of a single comment here. Essentially you'd need to create a listener and a client, connect, send some sort of header to say "hey, this is a file transfer, it's called 'filename.txt' and it's 140715 bytes long" and then send the data of the file. I'd recommend against doing this if you're a beginner though, since without proper authentication this would be a gaping security hole.